# Cypress test on WP: if I click on publish it does not update the page

Tags: wordpress, testing, click, cypress

[image]

I should click on this button. the html structure is as follows:

```
<div id="publishing-action">
   <span class="spinner"></span>
   <input name="original_publish" type="hidden" id="original_publish" value="Pubblica">
   <input type="submit" name="publish" id="publish" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Pubblica">
</div>
```

with cypress I give it the following command:

```
cy.get('input[type=submit]').contains('Pubblica').click({force:true})
```

but the page is not published

[image]

if instead I manually click on the button it gives me this:

[image]

Comment: can you post the error that you are getting ?

Comment: @AlapanDas I updated the post. Unfortunately it doesn't give me any errors. In click on the button but the page does not update

Comment: Just to debug can you put in like a 20 second wait after the click using `cy.wait(20000)`and check how the app behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
cy.get('#publish').should('have.value', 'Pubblica').contains('Pubblica').click()
```